# Deriving corresponding dates next to specific IDs in excel

Tags: excel

```
A                  B                  C
1001             23jan17            1002 
1002             22Jan17            1003    
1004             19jan17            1004
```

Above are customer IDs in Col A with their visit dates during a particular session. 
Column C is the carry same customer IDs list who showed for the next visit. It is very unlikely that all IDs in Col A will be in Col C .  Now I need to pull the corresponding dates of the customer IDs in Col C from Col B.

Answer (score 0):

In D2, you would write:

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
```

then drag it down to extend the formula. If there is a cell in column C that have a customer ID that doesn't appear in column A (like C3 in your example, that has 1003 which doesn't appear in column A) then you will get #N/A in that cell. You can use IFNA then to make it the value you want (like blank, or "Customer not found").